# Query Order By Number Variable From API

Tags: wp-query, order

Trying to order the query by a number variable $total that is a storing an api containing a number. My goal is to output an ordered list with the number ($total) sorting the list. I've looked around for a few different examples but nothing seems to work that I've stumbled across.

```
<?php 
      $shortcode = get_field('shortcode_for_data');
      $url = 'api.com/?SHORTCODE=' . $shortcode;
      $obj = file_get_contents($url);
      $json = json_decode($obj, true);

      $amountTotal = explode( '.', $json[0]['AMOUNT'] );

      $total = number_format($amountTotal[0]);

      //($total is outputting a number like 12,345 with a comma)

      $output = new WP_Query(array(
                  'post_type' => 'output',
                  'posts_per_page' => -1,
                  'meta_key' => $total,
                  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                  'order' => 'ASC'
                ));

      echo '<ol>';

      while($output->have_posts()) : $output->the_post(); ?>

       <li>
         <div><?php the_title(); ?></div>
         <div><?php echo $total ?></div>
       </li>

     <?php } wp_reset_postdata;?>

      <ol>
```

Goal (order by number):

Title Three   12,345
Title Two     11,345
Title One     999
Title Four    456

Comment: Hmm... Could you explain what exactly are you trying to accomplish? It’s pretty hard to guess what that code should be doing, I guess... What data do you store in what meta fields and what does that API return exactly?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I have added all of the code to give a complete idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: @Tripp which post meta key is this being stored in? And where is `$amount` coming from?

Comment: Amount is coming from an api as json. There is not meta key which is what I'm messing up. The number from the json is being stored in $total

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t get it. You’re getting some number from remote api and then use it as a meta_key. So all of your posts have millions of meta set? Or do you want to get a random number for every post and then order the posts by that number? (That’s the only think I can come up with that makes some sense, I guess...)

Comment: Sorry this is the key and what I failed to explain. Each post is assigned a different shortcode that is attached to the api as a parameter returning a specific number for each post. That unique number is assigned to each post and stored in $total